# How to change ColdFusion function to a similar PHP function

Tags: php, coldfusion

I am working with some code for uploading images to a server on android. I am working on my local xampp server. I do have Restler and PHP installed on it for REST services at the moment. 
[I was working modifying the code in this tutorial.](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)

I installed an external jar file for the http client errors. But I cannot install coldfusion as it appears to require a commercial license of some sort and this is what this tutorial is using. As I said, most of the code is in that tutorial besides downloading the latest http client jar file [here.](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) What I'm really asking is what alternatives to this cfc function are there? And preferrably what php alternatives are there? Please let me know if I should clarify anything else. Thank You.

Comment: You can install Railo which is an OSS CFML engine: http://www.getrailo.org/ or Open Blue Dragon: http://openbd.org/

Comment: I believe there is a developer's edition of coldfusion available free of charge from adobe.  I just don't know the link.

Comment: Here is a link for [Adobe CF Developer Edition](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=coldfusion). As mentioned, it is free for development. You might also give [Railo Express](http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/download/) a whirl. (No install needed. Just download an run.) Re: *what php alternatives are there* The only thing the `.cfc` does is upload a file and return a structure with details like (fileName, fileSize, etcetera). I am not that familiar with php, but it sounds very similar to [`$_FILES` ](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: You can also put on your flash drive the railo jetty version to port it from computer to computer.  Works like a charm for coding in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

Cormac, the only ColdFusion consideration here is that the blogger uses a CFC as a web service within one of their Java classes (it's not great to have a dependency like that in there, but oh well).  So what you're gonna need to do is to find out what that web service does, and roll your own. On the basis of the info you have given is, we can't tell you what the web service does... I recommend you touch base with the blogger and ask them. They'll almost certainly flick you the code, and then we can have a look at that if you need further help.

Comment: (oh, and I'll remove my down vote once you improve the question so that it's answerable)